# How to modify chartjs tooltip to add customized attribute

Tags: chart.js

How I have to edit the tooltip template that i can add customized attributes from my json file ? Below the example:

[ChartJS Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBjrx.jpg)

In the x-axis are the Months with the first letter, but in the tooltip i want to show the first three letters of the month - How can i do this ?

**EDIT:** My JSON File:

```
{"modules":[{
"name":"Chart 1",
"link":"www.google.com",
"type":"Bar",
"series":"SeriesA",
"data":[[20,40,50,40,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]],
"labels":["M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D","J","F","M","A","M"],
"colors":[{
    "fillColor":"blue"
    }],
"options":{
    "scaleShowGridLines":false
    }

    }]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Different Labels in Tooltip vs Scale

Just use the `tooltipTemplate` option

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
function Label(short, long) {
  this.short = short;
  this.long = long
}
Label.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.short;
}

var data = {
    labels: [ 
      new Label("J", "JAN"), 
      new Label("F", "FEB"), 
      new Label("M", "MAR"),
      new Label("A", "APR"),
      new Label("M", "MAY"),
      new Label("J", "JUN"),
      new Label("J", "JUL")
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

// create chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label.long%>: <%}%><%= value %>",
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7z1s1feg/

Comment: Short Question: As I am using Angular Chart JS aswell, how to modify there the json file to align with your solution ? Please see my json file in the main post above...

Comment: Can you post the version you have so far as a fiddle? I can patch in the above answer into that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[This part](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-external-tooltips) of the documentation explain you how to extend the tooltips elements.

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, {
    customTooltips: function(tooltip) {

    };
});
```

Plus, [this example](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/line-customTooltips.html) show you how to modify the HTML of the tooltip inside this function. The example from GitHub :

```
var innerHtml = '';
    for (var i = tooltip.labels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        innerHtml += [
            '<div class="chartjs-tooltip-section">',
            '   <span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="background-color:' + tooltip.legendColors[i].fill + '"></span>',
            '   <span class="chartjs-tooltip-value">' + tooltip.labels[i] + '</span>',
            '</div>'
        ].join('');
    }
    tooltipEl.html(innerHtml);
```

With these elements, you will be able to customize your tooltips however you want.